# How to get values not indexed in the first or in the last in a comma separated string but in the middle of the string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, database

I've a table:

```
id property_id keyword
1   1          Bangalore
2   2          Kolkata
```

I want the column values in comma-separated manner. So, I tried:

```
select (SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='cache_search') as result;
```

Which resulted in:

```
result
id,property_id,keyword
```

Now I want this result column to get split and I want each of the value separated by comma.
So, I tried:

```
select left(
   (SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME='cache_search'),
    locate(',',
   (SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME='cache_search')
   ) - 1) as result;
```

Which is returning:

```
result
id
```

and

```
select  substr(
          ( SELECT  group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
                FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE  TABLE_NAME='cache_search'),locate(',',
                  ( SELECT  group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
                        FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE  TABLE_NAME='cache_search')) + 1
          ) as result;
```

which retunr:

```
result
property_id,keyword
```

Again:

```
select  substr((substr(
                      ( SELECT  group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
                            FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                            WHERE  TABLE_NAME='cache_search'),locate(',',
                              ( SELECT  group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
                                    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                    WHERE  TABLE_NAME='cache_search')) + 1)
                  ),locate(',',(substr(
                              ( SELECT  group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
                                    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                    WHERE  TABLE_NAME='cache_search'),locate(',',
                                      ( SELECT  group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
                                            FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                            WHERE  TABLE_NAME='cache_search')) + 1))) + 1
      ) as result;
```

It returns:

```
result
keyword
```

But, nowhere I'm able to get **property_id** in the **result** column.
Any help is appreciated.

**Can I use the inside *SELECT* statement as a variable by using

*SET @variableName = 'value'*  this syntax? If yes HOW?**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow the logic of concatenating columns that you want to keep separate, and then splitting them up again.... why bother concatenating them in the first place?

Comment: I need an output that returns **property_id**  
i.e by the _2nd query_ I'm getting the `id` as `result` and by the **last** query I'm getting `keyword` as `result` but I wan't a query to return the `property_id` as a `result` also.  
Is it possible?  
Hope the requirement is clear now?

Comment: Because through:  
`(SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='cache_search')` it's returning the values in several rows. **These are not row or column values** these are the headers of the column. To get them separately I found to concatenate them in one string and split them up as the returned result is not having _ids_. 
Yet if there you have any easy solution please suggest. @Mark Baker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(rcat, ',', 1) as first_col,
       substring_index(substring_index(rcat, ',', 2), ',', -1) as col1,
       substring_index(rcat, ',', -1) as last_col
from (SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) as rcat
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME='cache_search'
     ) r
```

I moved the subquery to the `from` clause so it is easier to read.

Comment: Awesome.. It works smooth.. Yet can you please explain  just
`substring_index(substring_index(rcat, ',', 2), ',', -1) as col1` part?  
Why are you using `substring_index` inside `substring_index` I didn't get that part.

Comment: `substring_index()` returns parts of the string *up to* the nth part.  So, `substring_index('a,b,c', ',', 2)` returns "a,b", not "b".